# AngularJS routes vs. jQuery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs

I have just gotten started with AngularJS (coming from jQuery) and it seems worthwhile to replace a majority of my jQuery.

I decided that the easiest place to start was all the simple show / hide tabbed content I have. Currently, I have all the applicable html within the page that loads. However, it seems like I'd be better off loading the entirety of these tabbed sections using Angular routes. Am I correct in that assumption? Or should I use some hybrid approach (the content within these sections is dynamic)?

Anyway, with the Angular solution, I cannot seem to get the script to work for routes. I am in very new territory with this and am clueless as to where I am going wrong. Any help is grea

My currently HTML (simplified):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app='mainApp'>

<head>

    <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>

</head> 

<body>


<div class='toggleButtons'>

<a href='#/info'>
<div></div>
</a>

<a href='#/comment'>
<div></div>
</a>

<a href='#/feedback'>
<div></div>
</a>

</div>


<div class='container'>

<div data-ng-view=''></div>

</div>

<script src='app/main.app.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Angular:

```
/// <reference path="../js/angular.min.js" />

var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/info',
            {
                controller: 'mainInfoController', 
                templateUrl: '/app/partials/info.html'
            })

        .when('/comment',
            {
                controller: 'mainCommentController',
                templateUrl: '/app/partials/comment.html'
            })

        .when('/feedback',
            {
                controller: 'mainFeedbackController',
                templateUrl: '/app/partials/feedback.html'
            })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/app/partials/info.html' });


});
```

Just to note: the controllers above are just placeholders really. I have not created them yet. However, I don't care if they work or not now. I am just concerned with getting the partial view routes to show up. They aren't though. Clicking the links does properly show page.html#/info (or comment or feedback... etc.). But nothing happens.

Also file path is as follows:

- main folder = html

  - js = scripts
  - app = angular files (app.js / module files here)

    - views
    - partials
    - controllers
    - services

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you mean you have not created the controllers in your code

Comment: It works if you place the partials at the same level as the main html.

Comment: actually it works with paths such as app/partials/info.html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='mainApp'>

    <head>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

            mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

                $routeProvider

                .when('/info', {
                    controller: 'mainInfoController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/partials/info.html'
                })

                    .when('/comment', {
                    controller: 'mainCommentController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/partials/comment.html'
                })

                    .when('/feedback', {
                    controller: 'mainFeedbackController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/partials/feedback.html'
                })

                    .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/info'
                });

                function mainInfoController($scope) {}

                function mainCommentController($scope) {}

                function mainFeedbackController($scope) {}
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='toggleButtons'>
<a href='#/info'>
<div>Info</div>
</a>

<a href='#/comment'>
<div>Comment</div>
</a>

<a href='#/feedback'>
<div>Feedback</div>
</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: basically the only thing you need to change it your code is: remove leading forward slashed from the template url. Controllers are not essential at this stage.